Movie about female android who can also get pregnant
It's about a female android who can get pregnant. And she doesn't know she's an android until she gets beaten up pretty bad. Another thing that could help that there is violence involved and apparently a movie is from 2010 something like that.
I also have a pic of it but it doesn't helped me enough:


Looks like an exact match to Baby Boom which is a French short film, confirming from this poster:

I found a link of this film here, which is in French and even Google translate is also not helping me much. Don't confuse it with Baby Boom (1987) which I literally have done. 
Movie description says

In a bunker situated in the heart of a battlefield, three men - a priest, a sheriff and a mercenary - question an android female capable of reproducing the human existence. (Source:en.unifrance.org).

Youtube trailer for the film.
